# Nodejs - share variable created asynchronously between multiple files

Tags: node.js

I'm using NodeJS / Express.

In my `app.js`, I have a variable retrieved asynchronously that I want to share between multiple files:

```
const myDriver;
somePromise.then((driver) => myDriver = driver);
```

somePromise creates a driver instance of selenium.

**My goal:** share the value of `myDriver` between multiple files in my express project, after the promise has resolved, without executing the promise multiple times (so it won't create multiple selenium instances). I need to do it only when the app starts.

I couldn't find the right usage with module.exports since it's async.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. Basically save the instance somewhere so you can reuse it in subsequent calls.

```
let myDriver;

async function getDriver() {
  if (!myDriver) {
    myDriver = await somePromise();
  }

  return myDriver;
}

module.exports = getDriver;
```

usage

```
const driver = await getDriver();
```

Since it is await, you need to use async for the functions.

Comment: Can you share how do you import it from other file?

Comment: `const getDriver = require("driver.js");`